# Averaging Data in SQL

Tags: python, mysql, database

i have database with 5 columns.  ID,food,cost1,cost2,cost3 and average.How can i create some code on python that will let me average the 3 costs on the MySQL database then output them in the average column?

Comment: Do you have to do it in Python?

Comment: yes  it has to be in python but it ok to do it on sql aslong as it adds the score to the average column on the same table and it ignores the null values if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to do it in Python? You can do the operation in MySql.

```
SELECT
  AVG(cost1 + cost2 + cost3) AS avgcost
FROM foods
WHERE ...
```

**Update:** Per comment request (assuming your table name is `foods`):

```
SELECT *, AVG(cost1 + cost2 + cost3) AS avgcost
FROM foods
```

Comment: what would be the whole code? what would come after the where and would this be a averga that would ignore the null values

Comment: How would I know?! You haven't provided any table info or how you want to filter the rows...

Comment: ID= pk
food  = varchar
cost1 = int
cost2 = int
cost3 = int
average = int

Comment: It's the same info as in your question. I meant the table name and how you want to filter your table to form the `where` clause. But anyhow, I updated the question to do the average on all records.

Comment: my table name is food cost and i want to filter by ID

Comment: See my example above and adopt it ...

Comment: i dont know how :( im new to this

Comment: I can only suggest to take a basic sql course. There are plenty on YouTube as well... Don't spend your time trying to finish a task without understanding how it works. You will loose more hours in the long run!